# Remove or disable customer attribute added from migration from 1.9.3.2 to 2.1.4

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, migration, customer-attribute

I have migrated a site from 1.9.3.2 to 2.1.4 and there is a customer attribute `customerno` that was added from a module called `Fontis_Customer`. The old module has a file:

```
app/code/local/Fontis/Customer/Model/Entity/Setup.php

class Fontis_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup extends Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup
{
        'customerno' => array(
                'label'         => 'Customer Number',
                'visible'       => true,
                'required'      => true,
        ),
}
```

After migration it carried this attribute over and is preventing checkouts. When I click the button to checkout I get the error message `The value of attribute "customerno" must be set` I ran a query:

```
mysql> select * from eav_attribute ea INNER JOIN customer_eav_attribute cea ON cea.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id WHERE ea.frontend_label LIKE '%Customer%' \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
         attribute_id: 140
       entity_type_id: 1
       attribute_code: customerno
      attribute_model: NULL
        backend_model: NULL
         backend_type: varchar
        backend_table: NULL
       frontend_model: NULL
       frontend_input: text
       frontend_label: Customer Number
       frontend_class: NULL
         source_model: NULL
          is_required: 0
      is_user_defined: 0
        default_value: NULL
            is_unique: 0
                 note: NULL
         attribute_id: 140
           is_visible: 1
         input_filter: NULL
      multiline_count: 1
       validate_rules: NULL
            is_system: 0
           sort_order: 0
           data_model: NULL
      is_used_in_grid: 0
   is_visible_in_grid: 0
is_filterable_in_grid: 0
is_searchable_in_grid: 0
```

and I saw that the field `is_required` was set to 1. I set it to 0 thinking that would solve the problem but it doesn't. Is there somewhere else that this value is set to required in the database?

**EDIT:** I should note that I would prefer to do it at the database level instead of creating a module to do it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look : `vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Backend/AbstractBackend.php::validate()`

```
if ($attribute->getIsVisible()
    && $attribute->getIsRequired()
    && $attribute->isValueEmpty($value)
    && $attribute->isValueEmpty($attribute->getDefaultValue())
 ) {
       throw new LocalizedException(__('The value of attribute "%1" must be set', $attrCode));
 }
```

As we can see, this message occurs when: (using `and` conditions)

- `is_visible` set to 1.
- `is_required` set to 1.
- This attribute has no value.

In your case, after changing `is_required` to 0, the checkout process should works. Should try again with:

- Try to re-index database again.
- Clear Magento Cache.

Comment: Clearing the cache and re-indexing did the trick! thanks